# Chart Series jumps to first Value only when ScrollBar is clicked

Tags: c#, datetime, charts, scrollbar

I have a program with a chart and a Dictionary with my values. I add the Points to the Series by cycling the keys of the Dictionary with a foreach loop. Now my problem is I want to zoom into the chart, which I already accomplished but when the points are loaded the position of the scrollbar is on the date 01.01.1900 and when I click the scrollbar it jumps to the actual first date, which is 28.03.2020. How can I fix it so the scrollbar is already on this date?

I already tried to set the scaleview position to the minimum of my chartarea but that didn't work.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum;
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem by putting the following line of code after where i added my points to the chart:

`chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = chart1.Series[0].Points.First().XValue;`

Seems like the scale view always went to the oldest Date it knows, which is the 01.01.1900.